# Active Storage Rails 6 API unable to insert to active_storage_attachments table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

I am creating API endpoint for active storage with reactjs. My upload controller is as follows:  The code belows execute:

1. insert blob object in active_storage_blob - ok
2. Upload file to designated path in storage - ok
3. does not insert active_storage_attachments (polymorphic relation) I already add
   has_one_attached :photo

   ```
   class Api::V1::Activestorage::DirectUploadsController < 
         ActiveStorage::DirectUploadsController

         skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

        def create
           blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.create_before_direct_upload!(**blob_args)
           render json: direct_upload_json(blob)
        end

       private

       def blob_args
        params.require(:blob).permit(:filename, :byte_size, :checksum, :content_type, metadata: {}).to_h.symbolize_keys
       end

      def direct_upload_json(blob)
         blob.as_json(root: false, methods: :signed_id).merge(direct_upload: {
          url: blob.service_url_for_direct_upload,
          headers: blob.service_headers_for_direct_upload
        })
      end
    end
   ```

all are ok except for this active_storage_attachment table are not inserted. Hope someone can help. Thanks all

Comment: still cannot figure out for this issue. I am still stack hope someone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add a new method for attachment this is my refactor code. Hope this will help.

```
class Api::V1::UploadController < ActiveStorage::DirectUploadsController

 skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

 def create
     blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.create_before_direct_upload!(blob_args)
     render json: direct_upload_json(blob)
 end

 def attached_create
   ActiveStorage::Attachment.create(params_attached) #from react axios pass params
 end

 private

 def params_attached
    params.require(:attachment).permit(:name, :record_type, :record_id, :blob_id)
 end

 def blob_args
    params.require(:blob).permit(:filename, :byte_size, :checksum, :content_type, metadata: {}).to_h.symbolize_keys
 end

def direct_upload_json(blob)
    blob.as_json(root: false, methods: :signed_id).merge(service_url: url_for(blob)).merge(direct_upload: {
      url: blob.service_url_for_direct_upload,
      headers: blob.service_headers_for_direct_upload
    })
end
```